# How to identify and click checkbox based on text next to it - Selenium

Tags: checkbox

I am new to stackoverflow & test automation world so please treat me nicely.

Issue here is that, that I am trying to click the checkbox based on the text next to it i.e. Click the first checkbox if the text is 'Death certificate' (in the pic) i.e. based on the text next to it.

I'm not sure how to do it & need help here.

[Page Object & Firepath desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgZqy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thing here is you do not need to do like that. Because the checkbox next to 'Death Certifcate' is obviously infront of the 'Death Certificate' text. As same as the checkbox next to 'ID Document' is obviusly infront of the text 'ID Document'. So according to your requirement you have to check the checkbox next to 'Death Certificate' text. Just locate that **checkbox** using firepath and click on it. So the code must look similar to this.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the checkbox")).click();
```

Here if you want you can see whether it is selected using a conditon. 
**Ex** If the checkbox'Death Certificate' is not checked click on it. This is how to do it.

```
if(!driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).isSelected()){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lalindra for good explanation, the issue here is that the order of the text next to checkbox is dynamic i.e. I'm not sure where the 'Death Certificate' will appear next in the another scenario (it could be at second place, hence want to locate the Death Certificate text & then click checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to locate the text first.

```
String textValue = driver.findElement(By.className("container-fluid-label-required")).getText();

if(textValue.equals("Death Certificate")){
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the checkbox")).click();
}
else{
       //Do stuff
}
```

So now it first checks the text inside the div element is 'death certificate' And if it equals to 'death certificate' then it clicks on the checkbox. Hope this is the answer you were looking for.